# Can you update Google and JSON-LD?

Tags: google-search, json-ld

I am wondering, if I wish to update the JSON-LD on my website, can I? If so, do I just need to change the JSON-LD code, or do I need to tell google if there are any changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can update the JSON-LD on your website at any time. Google will automatically index it as part of the next crawl.

Comment: Thanks! Really puts my mind to ease knowing it is not permanent :D